# Cannot upload image into a table in database using MySQL and nestjs

Tags: mysql, nestjs

I'm learning about nestjs and MySQL. I have a problem when I try to upload image information to store into a table in the database. So please help me!

Comment: Hi Caroline, can you show us your code to know more about the problem you have?

Comment: Please share your code